# Single missing place from Facebook Graph API search results

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, search

I'm testing a place search based on a lat-lng and have found there is one place missing from the results when I run through the API results in PHP. The strange thing is, the place does show up in the results when I test the exact same query with Graph API Explorer. The Explorer returns 463 results, the query in PHP returns only 462. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

Query:

```
search?fields=likes,category,category_list,name,location,description,website,about,emails,phone,cover,picture&limit=500&offset=0&type=place&center=59.170418927333,18.140681162&distance=5000&access_token=[MY_TOKEN]
```

Missing place:

```
{
  "id": "773156306055683",
  "about": "Till dig kan du komma och äta en bit mat eller beställa en god drink i baren och stanna in på småtimmarna. ",
  "can_post": true,
  "category": "Food/Beverages",
  "category_list": [
    {
      "id": "273819889375819",
      "name": "Restaurant"
    }
  ],
  "checkins": 62,
  "cover": {
    "cover_id": "773157426055571",
    "offset_x": 0,
    "offset_y": 50,
    "source": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xal1/t31.0-8/s720x720/10682265_773157426055571_7318643765453322534_o.jpg",
    "id": "773157426055571"
  },
  "has_added_app": false,
  "is_community_page": false,
  "is_published": true,
  "likes": 10,
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/Grand-Brasseria-Natt-Club-773156306055683/",
  "location": {
    "city": "Handen",
    "country": "Sweden",
    "latitude": 59.170418927333,
    "longitude": 18.140681162,
    "street": "Stores Gränd 6",
    "zip": "136 46"
  },
  "name": "Grand Brasseria Natt Club",
  "name_with_location_descriptor": "Grand Brasseria Natt Club",
  "phone": "08-745 22 00",
  "talking_about_count": 0,
  "website": "http://www.brasseria.se",
  "were_here_count": 62
}
```

Comment: What kind of access token are you using in each case?

Comment: i used an app-token in php and a user-token in explorer. Can't see anything on that single place which would make it not appear for an app token though. Thanks!

Comment: The page is access restricted in some way (for alcohol-related content, by age, location, language) – and that means you can not request any info about it with an app token, you need to use a user access token for a user that can see the page, or a page access token.